# DBMS output not displaying

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbms-output

DBMS output not displaying

```
DECLARE
COUNT1 NUMBER;


BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO COUNT1
    FROM PROCESSPART
    WHERE DIV = '1'
     AND BK = '0G'
     AND BK_YR = '19';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCESSPART RECORDS IN GEN5 FOR LOC 1, BK 0G, BK_YR 2019');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COUNT1);

  END;
```

I have turned DBMS Output on in SQL Developer, and the window is there, connected to the DB. But when I run the block nothing appears in the window after successful completion.

Comment: did you turn on dbms_output in sqldeveloper? or from sqlplus - set serveroutput on

Comment: Yeah, i have it turned on and the window is there. connected to the DB but when i run the block nothing appears in the window after successful completion

Comment: *"nothing appears in the window"* - Not saying I don't believe you, but this seems excessively unlikely.

Comment: OP could be right - if they're on a newer version of SQL Developer and an older version of the DB like 10g, DBMS OUTPUT won't work due to jdbc driver compatibility issues

Comment: I'm not sure what the counting brings to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Why not just `begin dbms_output.put_line('Hello'); end;`

Answer (score 0):

Before your statements use the instruction below (as OldProgrammmer said) and run them together:

```
SET serveroutput ON

DECLARE
COUNT1 NUMBER;


BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO COUNT1
    FROM PROCESSPART
    WHERE DIV = '1'
     AND BK = '0G'
     AND BK_YR = '19';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCESSPART RECORDS IN GEN5 FOR LOC 1, BK 0G, BK_YR 2019');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COUNT1);

END;
```